# Concatenation of tokens from <c:forTokens>

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a use case where I will be given a string with words delimited using : and I need to break them in tokens and and reconstruct with space as delimiter.
I am trying something like this in my JSP:

```
<c:forTokens var="word" delims=":" items= "Amit:Kumar:Pandit"    varStatus="iterateor">
${word}
</c:forTokens>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSTL replace function

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:set var="string1" value="Amit:Kumar:Pandit"/>
<c:set var="word" value="${fn:replace(string1,':', ' ')}" />
${word}
```

**Updated with respect to the comment**

If you want to output only, ommitting the first you can lean on your *iterator* variable, like this

```
<c:forTokens var="word" delims=":" items= "Amit:Kumar:Pandit"    varStatus="iterator">
     <c:if test="${not iterator.first}">
        ${word} <br/>
    </c:if>
</c:forTokens>
```

if you want to store to a new variable, again ommiting the first you should do something like

```
<c:forTokens var="word" delims=":" items= "Amit:Kumar:Pandit"    varStatus="iterator">
    <c:set var="newArray" value="${iterator.index == 1 ? '' : newArray} ${word}" />
</c:forTokens>

${newArray}
```

Comment: Actually I want to learn the use of c:forTokens. Okay lets say if I want only kumar and pandit to be concatenated and not amit and the output as "Amit    kumar+Pandit"